# Vertical components in polymer

Tags: html, css, polymer

I created a component and I want to put 3 them vertical

I try this

```
<div flex layout vertical>
     <my-comp></my-comp>
     <my-comp></my-comp>
     <my-comp></my-comp>
 </div>
```

but this does not work..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using Polymer 1.0. Try this instead:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">

...

<div class="flex layout vertical">
  <my-comp></my-comp>
  <my-comp></my-comp>
  <my-comp></my-comp>
</div>
```

The [layout system in Polymer 1.0 now uses CSS classes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#layout-attributes), instead of attributes as in Polymer 0.5.

Comment: I dont know why, but this not work.. I have the iron-flex-layout and I imported it but this didnt work..

Comment: In this case, as @Paulie_D suggested, post more of your actual code in your question. Only then can we see what's going wrong.